# INDEX function to locate customer ID when entering Name

Tags: excel, vba

I've recently started working with Excel due to running my own business now. As with anything I do, I want my logs to be practical, efficient and most of all working correctly. I'm almost satisfied with what I got so far but I can't seem to figure out how to let Excel look up a customer ID.

Basically what I want is:

- In the first sheet I add a customer by name in column B, his assigned customer ID is in column A
- In sheet 2 I type in the name of the customer in column E and I want Excel to look up that lastname in sheet 1 and then add the related customer ID in sheet 2 in column A

The reason for this is that I have returning customers and I don't want them to have a new customer ID, I want them to have the same ID as they had previously without going through all my customers to look if they are a returning customer and if so what their customer ID is.

I've been playing around with the INDEX function as that seemed to be the function used for this kinda stuff, but I just can't figure it out.

I look forward to hearing your tips and tricks in regards to this issue, thanks in advance!

Marc

Comment: I would use a phone number or other numeric search as text can have typos and it will not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sheet 2 A2

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(E2,Sheet1!B:B,0),1)
```

This answer would work for you assuming Sheet1 stores ID in A, name in B, and your second sheet has you type the name in E.

Caveats being that matching based on typed names are extremely prone to error, it would have to be an exact match. Perhaps consider using data validation or a more robust solution in the medium term.

Comment: FWIW the `,1` is not needed as you are only referencing one column in the first criterion.

Comment: For some reason it returns a #N/A, that's kinda the reason why I posted here because I tried similar functions prior to coming here.

Comment: @Narc #N/A signifies a failure to match the name to a record on the first sheet, as we've said matching based on name is a bad start to begin with due to typing errors such as this. This is why ID fields are generally numeric and unique to avoid duplicates and will never change for a customer. A name change or an incorrect spelling in the first place would break any linkages if you proceed down the route of using name as the ID.

Comment: The names are spelled indentically, I double checked. But I get what you're saying though, how about turning it around? Let Excel fill in the name when I enter the customer ID, would that work you'd say?

Comment: @Zerk Alright so basically I figured out what I did wrong, it was a function misstype rather than a misstype in the name. Either way, is it possible to add a IF function to it so that it shows nothing instead of #N/A when nothing is entered (empty rows that don't have customers in it yet)?

Comment: You can test the match result to see if it results in an error. `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(E2,Sheet1!B:B,0)),"",INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(E2,Sheet1!B:B,0),1))`